# How can we create a AWS Glue Crawler to Crawl on S3 Bucket?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, datatables, aws-glue

Create glue Crawler for S3 Bucket in AWS

Firstly, I started with glue in aws. I make a glue crawler on aws accounts glue after that I also intoduce database and table name but I will confuse how to connect it with s3 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the AWS Glue Console and click on "Crawlers" in the left-hand navigation menu.
2. Click on the "Add crawler" button.
3. Give your crawler a name and click "Next".
4. Select "Data stores" as the data store type and choose "S3" as the data store.
5. Enter the S3 path where your data is stored, and click "Next".
6. In the "Add another data store" section, you can choose to add another S3 path or a JDBC data source if you have data stored in a relational database.
7. Choose "No" for "Add another data store" and click "Next".
8. Choose "Create a new IAM role" and give it a name. This role will be used by the crawler to access your S3 bucket.
9. Click "Next" to configure the frequency of the crawler run. You can choose to run it on demand or set a schedule.
10. On the "Configure the crawler's output" screen, choose "Database" as the output and create a new database to store the metadata catalog.
11. Click "Finish" to create the crawler.

The crawler will start crawling your S3 bucket and infer the schema of your data. It will create a metadata catalog that can be used to query and analyze your data. Once the crawler is done, you can view the metadata catalog in the Glue Data Catalog or use it to create Glue jobs, Athena queries, or other data processing pipelines.